# How to remove WPF ListViewItem selection in windows 7 

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-xp

I would like to turn off the selection on `ListViewItems`, I don't want the row to be  so when highlighted when the mouse is over it.
I installed the application on windows xp system and disable the row selection using the code below :

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <!--Disables selecting the row-->
         <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
     </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

That works, but the same code doesn't work in windows 7.

Comment: When I set focusable to false on my machine the ListViewItems can't be selectedt and on Mouse Hover over a LvItem nothing is highlighted ..(Win7)

Comment: Sounds like a Theme difference. Do you have different Themes in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Consider extracting the default Style for a ListViewItem and set all colors to Transparent. This solution has the benefit, that your ListView will look the same on Win7 and XP. This solution does not prevent the user to select an item, it just makes the selection invisible. May be that this Style can be simplified somewhat more. Here's my complete XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#75FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#40FFFFFF"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" />
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" />
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" IsSelected="True"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" />
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" />
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" />
            <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem" />
        </ListView>
        <Button Height="30"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead of a ListView.